# Why can't I use the '?.' operator?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
 var FirstName = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Namn.Fornamn).ToList();
```

But I want to make `Namn` a possible null value, so I tried this:

```
var FirstName = deserializedList.Select(item => item.Personpost.Namn?.Fornamn).ToList();
```

But I get multiple errors:

[image]

Why don't that method work?

Comment: what is the type of Fornamn?

Comment: Please, don't report errors with screenshots! This is not a good practice as the search engines won't be able to index the information you're providing. It's better you copy them and paste here.

Comment: The operator is new in C# 6. Perhaps you're using a older version of the language or the framework.

Answer (score -1):

What Visual Studio version do you have?

This syntax is supported only in c# 6 version (VS 2015)

Comment: this should be a comment